# Animate cmd fails due to x11

Tags: imagemagick

When using ImageMagick in Win10 I tried to use magick animate to convert a directory of svg into an animation
but I get this

```
animate: delegate library support not built-in '' (X11) @ error/animate.c/AnimateImageCommand/1431.
```

Does it mean that this is impossible in windows ? Can I add some extra dll to get this working. Is there an alternate magick command?

Comment: I think you are using an incorrect technique. Try `magick -delay 80 *.svg animated.gif`

Comment: That command works correctly. Thank you.

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an alternative command.

```
magick -delay 20 *.svg animated.gif
```

Thanks to [mark-setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell)